# Expanding a macro as the argument to \input results in undefined control sequence error

Tags: macros, conditionals, expansion, input, ifthenelse

I'm creating a package which defines a command that looks something like this:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[2]{
    \input{|"\mypackage@buildcommand{#1}{#2}"}
}
```

`mypackage@buildcommand` uses the ifthen package, which defines `\equal`.  However, when I use `\mycommand{x}{y}` in a LaTeX document that uses my package, I get an undefined control sequence error referring to `\equal`.  When my macro simply returns the result of the buildcommand instead of passing it to input, it works fine and outputs the command to the LaTeX document, but with that `\input` it just doesn't work.

**Edit**
Added relevant code that uses ifthen

```
\ifx\@empty\playtex@encoding
    \ifdefined\inputencodingname
        % Use inputenc encoding if defined
        \def\playtex@encoding{%
            % Treat utf8x as utf8
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\inputencodingname}{utf8x}}%
            {utf8}{\inputencodingname}%
        }
    \else
        \def\playtex@encoding{utf8}
    \fi
\fi

\newcommand{\playtex@buildcommand}[2]{%
    playtex-render \playtex@playerfile{} #1 #2 %
    --encoding=\playtex@encoding{} %
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\playtex@cache}{always}}{--cache}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\playtex@cache}{never}}{--no-cache}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\playtex@cache}{draft}}{%
        \ifdraft{--cache}{--no-cache}%
    }{{\errmessage{cache must be always, never, or draft}}}}}%
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: A command defined in terms of `\ifthenelse` is not expandable, so you can't use it in that context.

Comment: What alternatives do I have to \ifthenelse?  I'm using it there to determine the command-line argument to pass to a shell command based on the value of a macro.  I'm also using \ifdraft from the ifdraft package, which I think is similar

Comment: Can you please show your definition of `\mypackage@buildcommand` so a different strategy can be suggested?

Comment: I added relevant code

Comment: your first fragment uses `\mypackage@buildcommand` and the second fragment defines `\playtex@buildcommand`  are they intended to be the same? You are not helping anyone to debug your code if it can not be run. But as egreg says you can not use ifthenelse in that context. You could use `\ifthenelse` on the outside and build the whole command so `\ifthenelse{\equal{\playtex@cache}{always}}{\input{|"playtex-render \playtex@playerfile\@space #1 #2 --cache"}{.....`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an expandable test, which `\ifthenelse` isn't. Also `{}` should not be used to delimit macro names in that context and `\space` should be used.

I changed the command into `echo` just for testing purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifequalstring}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[2]{%
  \input{|"\playtex@buildcommand{#1}{#2}"}%
}

\ifdefined\inputencodingname
  % Use inputenc encoding if defined
  \edef\playtex@encoding{%
    % Treat utf8x as utf8
    \ifequalstring{\inputencodingname}{utf8x}{utf8}{\inputencodingname}%
  }%
\else
  \def\playtex@encoding{utf8}%
\fi

\newcommand{\playtex@buildcommand}[2]{%
%  playtex-render \playtex@playerfile\space #1 #2 %
  echo \playtex@playerfile\space #1 #2 %
    --encoding=\playtex@encoding\space
    \ifequalstring{\playtex@cache}{always}
      {--cache}
      {%
       \ifequalstring{\playtex@cache}{never}
         {--no-cache}
         {%
          \ifequalstring{\playtex@cache}{draft}
            {\ifdraft{--cache}{--no-cache}}
            {\errmessage{cache must be always, never, or draft}}%
         }%
      }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter % for testing
\def\playtex@playerfile{FILE}
\def\playtex@cache{always}
\makeatother

\texttt{\mycommand{A}{B}}

\end{document}
```

### Output

> `FILE A B --encoding=utf8 --cache`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by pulling out all the conditionals from the macros and using the conditionals to define different macros.  I created a cachearg macro for the `--cache` argument and in the input I just put all my "static" macros together.  I also had to create a `\playtex@space` macro, set to a space character, because the `\macro{}` syntax doesn't work in the `\input` context to stop the macro from gobbling up stuff after it for whatever reason.  In @DavidCarlisle's comment, I see he used a `\@space` macro which seems to do the same thing, but I tried replacing my `\playtex@space` with `\@space` and it wasn't defined.  Don't know if it is supposed to be by default.

The whole thing is rather ugly and inflexible: for example, if the inputenc encoding was to change, my package would not update automatically like it would with conditionals in the macro.  That said, it works.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: `\@space` is probably a typo and `\space` was meant